# Jquery Ajax request requires mouse movement to update screen?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a fairly straight forward system which consists of one large screen showing the status of order numbers and a user screen (iPad) where they are changed.

Both are simple html/php pages and were working fine an hour ago.

The main screen is set to refresh every 3 seconds with the following code (this is the only actual script in this page).

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    setInterval(timingLoad, 3000);
    function timingLoad() {
        $('#main').load('update_divs.php #main', function() {
        });
    }
});
```

This is all setup on a small standalone Linux pc running as a LAMP server with no internet access.

The refresh runs 3 very basic php SQL requests to populate the Div with current position.

According to the user it has been working fine all afternoon but now will not update unless the mouse is moved, as soon as the mouse has had any movement the screen immediately updates to the latest position. This is not at all ideal as there shouldn't even be a need for a mouse to be connected to the PC.

Is it possible that I'm refreshing the page too often and somehow causing a memory issue or is this some other issue that people are aware of?

I've told them to restart the PC when they get a chance and I feel (as I've not heard from them in last half hour) that this has resolved it but obviously it is possibly going to happen again if I can't resolve it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: So you are saying it is not redrawing the page after the application sits for awhile. It has nothing to do with caching of the GET request.

Comment: Could you rule out that it's not a cache problem? When moving the mouse are the data updated?

Comment: Yes, as soon as the mouse is moved the screen correctly updates, I've not seen it myself but I believe that it then sits until the next mouse movement before it updates again.

Comment: Could it be a special browser? Or does it happen with other browsers too?

Comment: Was using Firefox, once the machine had restarted it worked again so unable to check that. If it happens again then I'll load it up in Chrome or even IE (shudder).

Comment: A further update, where they said they had to move the mouse to get the screen refresh. Firefox is set to full screen, the refresh took place only when they moved the mouse to the top of the screen ie to force the url bar etc to reappear. At that point the screen would update.